# What's the best way to track conversions on an Android app?

Tags: android

We have an Android app for which we need to track the conversion at various steps. For example, our users have to fill out a form that has several steps on different pages. We need to be able to know what's the conversion for these various steps and attribute these conversions to our various acquisition channels (Google Ads, Facebook Ads, etc.).

What we have now is events set up thanks to the Facebook SDK as well as the Google Analytics Services SDK. The problem is that some of our events can be logged multiple times (for example if the user leaves the app and opens it again), thus rendering the analysis impossible (Unique Events don't work because we don't get the number of events per user but per user session).

Is there a way to properly track app conversions thanks to Google Analytics? Would it be easier to track conversions with the Firebase SDK?

Comment: after each step send a call to your server and let the server update the db. then with analytics, you can track conversions.